# Series evaluation using term products

Tags: sequences-and-series

Take some $f(x)$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{f(n)}  = x$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{af(n)+b}  = mx+n$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{1}{{f(n)}(af(n)+b)}  = px+q$$

Let us say that I know the value of $a,b,m,n,p,q$ and they are all rational numbers. Is there anyway to find the value of $x$ in terms of these six values if I know that $x$ is a positive real number?

Note: $f(n)$ need not necessarily be a polynomial function

Comment: Multiply the whole equation with $a$ to eliminate this coefficient and introduce new $b',m',n',p',q'$. Then you only have to deal with 5 coefficients.

Comment: No. Here, I know all the six values, which makes it an advantage. I don't care about what happens to the six values I know but whether or not I can find $x$ in terms of these values